# Less sensitive string comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

*answered* thanks to all that helped. I'm new to stack overflow as far as posting so if my edit is messy i apologize. the code below is what i ended up coming up with and think it may help others though i believe the person who answered last may also produce similar results.

I have been searching for a while now and I am sure I could break this down and get it done with a couple of sloppy if statements but I am looking for a common, efficient way.

I have a search with typical string comparison. For each string in an array using `NSRange`,  but the results I get from that can be picky.

If I have a string for example `Bat Man` I could find it with searching `Bat` or `Man` but not once I add an `m` onto `bat` for `Batm`.

I guess what im looking for, is if the characters exist within the string and not exactly that string.

```
     -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{


[roomsList removeAllObjects];
stringScore = 0;


// clear
if([searchText length] == 0){

    searchingRooms = NO;

    [roomsList addObjectsFromArray:[newDataManager shared].rooms];
    [self.gsgSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

    // search users
}else{



    searchingRooms = YES;

  for(QBChatRoom *room in [newDataManager shared].rooms){
      stringScore = 0;
      NSString*   newRoomNameText = [room.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@""];

      NSString* newSearchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];




      for(int i = 0 ;i<[newSearchText length]; i++) {
          char mySearchChar = [newSearchText characterAtIndex:i];

          lastSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",mySearchChar];

          NSRange searchRange = [newRoomNameText rangeOfString:lastSearchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
          if (searchRange.location != NSNotFound){
              stringScore = stringScore + 1;
              if (stringScore == newSearchText.length) {
                  [roomsList addObject:room];

              }



          }}}}


[gsgTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What if you just lowercase both strings and strip out any characters other than `[a-z]` before running your comparison?

Comment: may work ill give this a shot now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use predicates to solve this problem. They come in very handy while filtering arrays.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Self contains[c] %@",self.searchString.text];

NSArray *filteredArray = [self.superHeroesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Adding `[c]` after `contains` makes sure that the search is case insensitive.